# assign values groupwise using the group name as input

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably an easy one but I couldn't figure it out.

I have two dataframes

```
import numpy as np
import pandas 

da0 = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                               'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                        'B' : ['two', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                               'three', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
                        'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                        'D' : np.random.randn(8)
                       })

da1 = pandas.DataFrame({'E' : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
                        'F' : ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
                       })
```

I would like to add a new column to `da0`. This column should should take the values from column `'F'` in `da1` corresponding to the matching between `'E'` in `da1` and `'B'` in `da0`. In the example, the result should be

```
da0 = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                               'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                        'B' : ['two', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                               'three', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
                        'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                        'D' : np.random.randn(8),
                        'new': ['beta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'gamma', 
                                'alpha', 'beta', 'beta'] 
                       })
```

I tried grouping `da0` by `'B'` and then using transform but then I didn't know how to use the name of the group in the custom function.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way:

```
da0['new'] = da0['B'].map(da1.set_index('E')['F'])
```

**Result**

```
     A      B         C         D    new
0  foo    two -0.616481 -0.679958   beta
1  bar    one  1.721246 -0.985037  alpha
2  foo    two  0.782059 -0.694043   beta
3  bar  three -1.088806  1.855281  gamma
4  foo  three  0.302535  0.042422  gamma
5  bar    one  1.893247 -1.218680  alpha
6  foo    two -2.337719 -0.077325   beta
7  foo    two  0.137897  1.709476   beta
```

**Explanation**

- [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) may take a Series as an input.
- Using `set_index` ensures the values from `da0['B']` aligns with `da1['E']`.

Comment: Follow-up question: in my real dataset B takes thousends of names but each of them is repeated around 100 times. That is why I originally asked for a groupwise operation, because I think it would run faster. So how can I apply it on `da0.groupby('B')`?

Comment: Can you check how long it actually takes with the above method? The reason I ask is because the speed should be dictionary-like, which should be fast for even a few million mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `replace`

```
da0['New']=da0.B.replace(dict(zip(da1.E,da1.F)))
da0
Out[2004]: 
     A      B         C         D    New
0  foo    two  0.399663  1.236391   beta
1  bar    one  0.903984  0.640332  alpha
2  foo    two -0.025079 -0.420485   beta
3  bar  three  1.696489  0.023614  gamma
4  foo  three  0.669597  1.628613  gamma
5  bar    one -2.033584  0.081647  alpha
6  foo    two -0.207683  0.058281   beta
7  foo    two -0.571093  0.436593   beta
```